# Change select list based off of form input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to create an RSVP form for my wedding.  Each invite will have a three digit ID hand written on them.  The ID will start with the number of people in that party that are invited. Example: ID: 302 = (3)three people were invited and (02) the ID for the invited guest(s).

We want to go this route to limit people from RSVPing more than the amount invited, all while getting an accurate count of attendees.

So if someone types their ID in on the form, Example 302, there will be a select list available for three or fewer guests. 514 would have 1 - 5 select list available and so on.

How could I accomplish this in jQuery or Ajax?

Comment: The ID is getting entered into a text field, thus changing the select list size. That is all. I do not need to have an associated DB or use Ajax, I just wanted to see options.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XmpqN/?

Comment: I posted my example as an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't up-vote because I'm new.  But thank you for your work. Big help.

Comment: No problem, but you can accept the answer if you feel it answered your question. That'll increase your rep and put you on the road to upvoting and commenting on other's questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started:

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">ID
    <input name="code" type="text" size="3" />
    <button type="button">Proceed</button>
    <label>Guests
        <select name="guests"></select>
    </label>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $.trim($('input[name=code]').val());
    var guests = code.substr(0, 1);
    $('select[name=guests]').empty();
    if ($.isNumeric(code)) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= guests; i++) {
            $('select[name=guests]').append('<option>' + i + '</option>');
        }
        $('label').css('display', 'block');
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XmpqN/)**